# All MVC3 App failing at runtime for same reason

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am starting to learn MVC(3) following a tutorial. I am a developer so I know basics and I cannot find an answer on the web that is relavent enough to fix my issue.

All the MVC apps are the default start up code. I select an "internet application" and choose to user HTML5. F6, build works. Rebuild works. F5, debugging is a different story.

Compiler Error Message: CS1541: Invalid reference option: 'C:\Users\Other\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\f20fc565\816eddc7\App_global.asax.lsdrp-bk.dll' -- cannot reference directories

I have searched my disc and no "App_global.asax.lsdrp-bk.dll" exists at all. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shut down all of your visual studio web servers running in your system tray.

Delete everything from:

C:\Users\Other\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\

That's your first step.That's a good starting point.
The error shows up as:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2zyc8wkc(v=vs.90).aspx
where it thinks App_global.asax.lsdrp-bk.dll is a folder for some strange reason.

Also if you reference any other projects in your solution, re-add those references.

Comment: To shut down the server from the system tray `Right-click -> "Stop"`

Comment: I'm afraid that hasn't made any difference. the only references I have are the ones which are created on the creation of the project.

Comment: I have just noticed that if I type the URL of a method "http://localhost:49426/HelloWorld", it works as expected?

Comment: What was the initial URL you were trying? Just the root / or /home/index or ?

Comment: When I debug it goes to "localhost:49426".

Comment: No one else to shed any light on the matter?

Comment: and if you specify /Home/Index  ?